# json encode array from php sql server and convert to Android

Tags: php, android, sql-server, json

Hi i am new in android php client server. At present, i am doing the response from php sql server sending to Android client multiple result from sql row. Previously, i sending a simple string and receive android like below:

```
$result_data = array( 
'ResultArray' => 'success',
); 

 #Output the JSON data 
 echo json_encode($result_data);
```

Then in android:

```
// Create a JSON object from the request response
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

//Retrieve the data from the JSON object
String resultLoging = jsonObject.getString("ResultArray");
```

Now i want to receive from database having 3 columns: id, phone, name. How would i do that? Thank for your helping

Comment: Will you paste your response.Then we will provide you exact solution

Comment: In the similar way as it was answered in bazillion similar questions here

Comment: the code above just example with my simple string encode. I want arrays with multiple result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following format in php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM tablename") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 

{

    // looping through all results

    // products node

    $response["details"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

 {

        // temp user array

        $product = array();

        $product["id"] = $row["id"];

        $product["name"] = $row["name"];

array_push($response["details"], $product);

    }

    // success

    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response

    echo json_encode($response);
```

In android

get success value

```
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

get the datas using following format

```
JSONArray spi = json.getJSONArray("details"); 

Use a for loop to get the object values in the array

for (int i = 0; i < spi.length(); i++) 
{

                        JSONObject c = spi.getJSONObject(i);

 id = c.getString("id");

}
```

Comment: id = c.getString("id");
this id is array or string?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONArray for multiple json result :

```
JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("ResultArray");
```

Iterate JSONArray and get value from JSONObject :

```
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
     JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String id = json.getString("id");
     String phone = json.getString("phone");
     String name = json.getString("name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result_data = array( 
'ResultArray' => 'success',
); 

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result_data));
```

in android

```
     JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
     JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("url of php file");
     JsonArray arry = json.getJSONArray("result");
     JSONObject c = arry .getJSONObject(0);
     String resultarr= c.getString("ResultArray");





 public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }            

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
      //  System.out.println(json);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {





        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

   }
  }
```

Comment: And from which library is jsonparser? Also if it is a parser why it has method called getJSONFromUrl?

Answer (score 0):

just found this, would be the best for my question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3563464/1345454

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $results[] = array(
      'title' => base64_decode($row['title']),
      'price' => $row['price'],
      'seller_user' => $row['user']
   );
}
$json = json_encode($results);
```